# How to break the loop when a specific string is entered when using getchar?

Tags: c++, char, byte

Consider this code:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    int c;
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
        if (c == '\t') {
            std::cout << '\\';
            std::cout << 't';
        }
        if (c == '\b') {
            std::cout << '\\';
            std::cout << 'b';
        }
        if (c == '\\') {
            std::cout << '\\';
            std::cout << '\\';
        }
        if (c == "break") {
            exit(c);
        } else {
            std::cout << c;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

As we all know, `char` only has 1 byte. So if I want to do `c == "break"`, the IDE raises such an error: `error: ISO forbids comparison between pointer and integer [-fmprermissive]`.

But if I change the double quotation marks to single quotation marks, the IDE raises a warning: `warning: character constant too long for its type. And the consequence of this is the whole code malfunctions.`

---

### Conclusion

How do I add bytes for char to let the code run successfully?

Comment: You are reading char by char, so you need to reconstruct sequence of char to catch  "break".

Comment: Word on the street is to use set of bytes, aka string

Comment: `c` will not equal `"break"`. "Adding bytes to `char`" is not a solution to this issue. You rather need to find out what `getchar` returns when `break` key is hit

Comment: It's not really clear what you want to do. Do you want to do something when the user enters the string `"break"` (use `std::string` then) or do you want to catch a special key? (Have only german keyboard currently, break-key == pause-key?)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because OP hasn't clarified what specific program behavior they want. The character sequence "break", or a single character that represents `break`. (newline, CTRL-D, etc.)

Comment: Do you mean `\d` with "break"?

Answer (score 2):

What you could do is use `std::vector` to store the input buffer and then compare it.

Here's the solution:

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::vector<char> input;
    std::string breakString = "break";

    int c;
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
    {
        // check if our input vector length is greater than the break string length
        if (input.size() >= breakString.size())
        {
            // get the last characters in the input buffer
            std::string lastInput(input.data() + input.size() - breakString.size(), breakString.size());

            // compare it with the break string
            if (lastInput == breakString)
            {
                break;
            }
        }

        input.push_back(static_cast<char>(c));
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: its not 100% clear from the quesiton but I suppose OP wants to detect the break-key being hit rather than `b`, `r`,`e`,`a` and `k`

Comment: @thedemons You need to include <cstring> and <iostream> to let the code work.