# How can I continue repeating switch until user inputs 'Exit'?

Tags: c++, loops, while-loop, do-while

I'm trying to create a calculator program that keeps on looping until the user types in 'Exit'. I got the calculator part down but I don't know how to make it continue looping until the user types in 'Exit'. I tried putting the switch in a while loop but that ended up repeating a+b=result.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

float Add(float num1, float num2) { return num1 + num2; }

float Sub(float num1, float num2) { return num1 - num2; }

float Div(float num1, float num2) { return num1 / num2; }

float Mul(float num1, float num2) { return num1 * num2; }

int main() {
  float a, b, result;
  char op;
  cout << "Calculator \n";
  cout << "_______________________________ \n";
  cout << "Number 1: ";
  cin >> a;
  cout << "Number 2: ";
  cin >> b;
  cout << "Operator(+, -, /, *): ";
  cin >> op;
  cout << "_______________________________ \n";

  switch (op) {
  case '+':
    result = Add(a, b);
    break;
  case '-':
    result = Sub(a, b);
    break;
  case '/':
    result = Div(a, b);
    break;
  case '*':
    result = Mul(a, b);
    break;
  default:
    result = 0;
    cout << "invalid operator!! \n";
  }
  cout << a << " " << op << " " << b << " = " << result;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Since `"Exit"` cannot fit in a single `char`, change `char op` to `std::string op` and work it out from there.

Comment: Read the input as a *string*. Then check if it's equal to `"Exit"` (or any variant). If not, and the input is only a single character get that character and use your current `switch`.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72854969/13253010) might answer your question.